# Highlighting in contenteditable div edge case

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on making a contenteditable div text highlighted or unhighlighted. But I am facing an edge case in which if I drag my mouse over the text end to end with wild dragging, my div is also getting selected. Which means if I print the range it gives me the parent element as the end container.

```
<div class = "XYZ">
 <span class = "highlighted">ABCD</span>
</div>
```

when I log range.endContainer it prints XYZ.

Also I am using range.setStart() and range.setEnd() methods to adjust my range which means I fail in the following scenario :

```
<div class = "XYZ">
 <span class = "unhighlighted">ABCD</span>
</div>


range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endContainer.textContent.length)
```

I am sure that I have made mistake in setting the end part of the range but I cannot figure out where ... can anybody help?

Comment: maybe because span elements are `display: inline` try css: `display: block`

Comment: No I don't want the span to be displayed in block.